# How to figure out gematria total with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a PHP application that calculates gematria. Gematria is a secret language that turns words into numbers. I got it to work with words that don't have a duplicate letter.

Words that work:

- Tesla
- abcde

Words that don't work:

- aaa ( has multiple a's )
- monsanto ( has 2 o's )

```
  /**
  * English Gematria Values
  *
  * @return array $array An array of key value pairs
  */

  function english_values() {
    $values = array(
      'a' => 6,
      'b' => 12,
      'c' => 18,
      'd' => 24,
      'e' => 30,
      'f' => 36,
      'g' => 42,
      'h' => 48,
      'i' => 54,
      'j' => 60,
      'k' => 66,
      'l' => 72,
      'm' => 78,
      'n' => 84,
      'o' => 90,
      'p' => 96,
      'q' => 102,
      'r' => 108,
      's' => 114,
      't' => 120,
      'u' => 126,
      'v' => 132,
      'w' => 138,
      'x' => 144,
      'y' => 150,
      'z' => 156,
    );
    return $values;
  }


  function calculator( $word ) {
    $split   = array_flip( str_split( $word ) );
    $english = array_intersect_key( english_values(), $split ); 
    return $english; 
  }

  print_r( calculator( 'tesla ') );
  echo "</br></br>";
  print_r( calculator( 'monsanto ') );
```

The output is:

> Array ( [a] => 6 [e] => 30 [l] => 72 [s] => 114 [t] => 120 )
>
> Array ( [a] => 6 [m] => 78 [n] => 84 [o] => 90 [s] => 114 [t] => 120 )

You can see tesla was able to go through each letter.  But Monsanto missed the last o so there is no way I will be able to calculate a correct total.

I would also like the letters to be in order of the word so tesla would output:

> Array ( [t] => 120 [e] => 30 [s] => 114 [l] => 72 [a] => 6 )

I may be using the wrong PHP functions to handle this so I would appeciate any help in the right direction.  I haven't coded in a while so I am a bit rusty.  I tried multiple PHP functions but this seemed to get me the closest to what I need to do.  Thank you.

Edit: I also understand the reason the duplicate letters don't show is because there can not be duplicate keys.  So I assume I am doing this probably pretty backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this moves you forward:

```
print_r(encodeWord('monsanto'));

function encodeWord($word) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
        $encodedWord[] = [
            'letter' => $word[$i],
            'convertedLetter' => convertLetter($word[$i]),
        ];
    }

    return $encodedWord;
}

function convertLetter($letter) {
    $values = [
        'a' => 6,
        'b' => 12,
        'c' => 18,
        'd' => 24,
        'e' => 30,
        'f' => 36,
        'g' => 42,
        'h' => 48,
        'i' => 54,
        'j' => 60,
        'k' => 66,
        'l' => 72,
        'm' => 78,
        'n' => 84,
        'o' => 90,
        'p' => 96,
        'q' => 102,
        'r' => 108,
        's' => 114,
        't' => 120,
        'u' => 126,
        'v' => 132,
        'w' => 138,
        'x' => 144,
        'y' => 150,
        'z' => 156,
    ];

    return $values[$letter];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is great.  Monsanto = 666 by the way.   I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the double letters, seems that the functions you used won't be able to see them. Maybe you should do your own function, as ghatzhat just answered.

And for the letters to appear in the same order as the given word, you just have to switch the parameters in array_intersect_key() call. So :

```
$english = array_intersect_key( $split , english_values() );
```

instead of

```
$english = array_intersect_key( english_values(), $split );
```